# Implementing a 2D Platformer Game Engine

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, physics

Any ideas where I can find info about making 2D jump & run games? I need some general ideas, so I wouldn't reinvent wheel (at least where game design is concerned).

Another point is that I am thinking of using boxes instead of images for collision testing. However, it should possible that I can implement slopes. Commander Keen 4+ is a good example of my idea.

Actually, what is troubling me is of course the collision testing and simple physics (mainly gravity).

I've got to build the engine myself and it for the J2ME.

Thanks a lot, guys!

Comment: J2ME? Do I smell a school project? :P

Comment: I would suggest looking at the XNA's Platformer Starter Kit (C#, I know)...but it appears to be taken down.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3431/ covers 2D physics, http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/ specifically in a platformer context. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3107/ covers 2D map editing.

Comment: @Bart, no school project here. I am thinking of making some money :-D @Joe, thank you very, very, *very* much!

Comment: Hmmm, but if you want to make money, is J2ME the best platform? Do people seriously game with that?

Comment: Well, @Bart, you have a point there. But there are some external factors to consider as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are some ideas from Sonic games: [Sonic Physics Guide](http://info.sonicretro.org/Sonic_Physics_Guide).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks really helpful! Just the kind of guide I wanted.

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of that link :o) If you have more of such technical indepth analysis, please share!

Answer (score 2):

You could always find some simple open source projects that are similar to what you want to build, and see how they structure their project. 
Also, there are plenty of tutorials around the web. A few are:

- [Creating 2D Action Games with the Game API](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/game/)
- [Java Game Development Series](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/game-programming/)
- [Writing Java Games: How we did it](http://www.essentialmath.com/JavaGame.pdf)
- [Space Invaders 101](http://www.cokeandcode.com/info/tut2d.html) (this one is good, it goes through creating a simple game)

If you are looking for a game framework to use, there is a good list at stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293079/java-2d-game-frameworks)

Answer (score 1):

In [Game Feel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123743281) by Steve Swink, he covers a lot of great design topics, including a detailed breakdown of the movement feel in platformers. Worth a peek.

Comment: Thanks! Really great book. Has a lot to say about game design.